# Using Rtexttools lib for machine learning

Tags: r, svn, machine-learning

I have the following training set:

```
    Text,y
    MRR 93345,1
    MRR 93434,1
    MRR 93554,1
    MRR 938900,1
    MRR 93970,1
    MRR 937899,1
    MRR 93868,1
    MRR 938769,1
    MRR 93930,1
    MRR 92325,1
    MRR 931932,1
    MRR 933922,1
    MRR 934390,1
    MRR 93204,1
    MRR 93023,1
    MRR 930982,1
    MRR 87678,-1
    MRR 87956,-1
    MRR 87890,-1
    MRR 878770,-1
    MRR 877886,-1
    MRR 87678367,-1
    MRR 8790,-1
    MRR 87345,-1
    MRR 87149,-1
    MRR 873790,-1
    MRR 873493,-1
    MRR 874303,-1
    MRR 874343,-1
    MRR 874304,-1
    MRR 879034,-1
    MRR 879430,-1
    MRR 87943,-1
    MRR 879434,-1
    MRR 871984,-1
    MRR 873949,-1
```

My code as follows:

```
# Create the document term matrix
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(data["Text"],language="english", removePunctuation=TRUE, stripWhitespace=TRUE,
                          toLower=TRUE,
                          removeStopwords=TRUE,
                          stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998) 

# Configure the training data
container <- create_container(dtMatrix, data$y, trainSize=1:nrow(dtMatrix), virgin=FALSE) 
# train a SVM Model
model <- train_model(container, "SVM", kernel="linear" ,cost=1)

# new data
predictionData <- list("MRR 93111") 

# create a prediction document term matrix 
predMatrix <- create_matrix(predictionData, originalMatrix=dtMatrix,language="english", removePunctuation=TRUE, stripWhitespace=TRUE,
                            toLower=TRUE,
                            removeStopwords=TRUE,
                            stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998) 

# create the corresponding container
predSize = length(predictionData);
predictionContainer <- create_container(predMatrix, labels=rep(0,predSize), testSize=1:predSize, virgin=FALSE) 

# predict
results <- classify_model(predictionContainer, model)
```

Now by using the train_model function I'd like to predict: MRR 93111 as y=1.
This means if the string starts with "MRR 93" the output should be 1, whereas the stem "MRR 87" gives -1. Actually it doesn't work, since I get `MRR 93111        -1 0.5778781`

Moreover it seems that the result changes if I sort out the training-set differently... or if I run the script several times against the same data-set, which sounds quite weird to me.

UPDATE1: dput(data)

```
structure(list(Text = structure(c(26L, 28L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 35L, 21L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 10L, 20L, 14L, 
13L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 
19L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("MRR 87149", "MRR 871984", "MRR 87345", 
"MRR 873493", "MRR 873790", "MRR 873949", "MRR 874303", "MRR 874304", 
"MRR 874343", "MRR 87678", "MRR 87678367", "MRR 877886", "MRR 878770", 
"MRR 87890", "MRR 8790", "MRR 879034", "MRR 87943", "MRR 879430", 
"MRR 879434", "MRR 87956", "MRR 92325", "MRR 93023", "MRR 930982", 
"MRR 931932", "MRR 93204", "MRR 93345", "MRR 933922", "MRR 93434", 
"MRR 934390", "MRR 93554", "MRR 937899", "MRR 93868", "MRR 938769", 
"MRR 938900", "MRR 93930", "MRR 93970"), class = "factor"), Y = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L)), .Names = c("Text", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Comment: Could you provide us dput instead of writing out your training set?

Comment: UPDATE1: Do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your code uses the training data and classification on a word level.

```
> dtMatrix$dimnames$Terms
 [1] "87149"    "871984"   "87345"    "873493"   "873790"   "873949"   "874303"   "874304"   "874343"   "87678"    "87678367"
[12] "877886"   "878770"   "87890"    "8790"     "879034"   "87943"    "879430"   "879434"   "87956"    "92325"    "93023"   
[23] "930982"   "93111"    "931932"   "93204"    "93345"    "933922"   "93434"    "934390"   "93554"    "937899"   "93868"   
[34] "938769"   "938900"   "93930"    "93970"    "mrr"
```

I'm not entirly sure of how excatly SVM treats these number strings but it seems not to care much for the 93 part of the strings. Splitting the strings into caharcter lays a bigger weight on the individual numbers:

```
df$Text <- sapply(1:length(df$Text), function(i) paste(unlist(strsplit(df$Text[i], split = "")), collapse = " "))
```

I'm using df instead of data since data is an object in RTextTools already and gave me some issues while running your code. WHile creating the matrix the option for min word length must be changed.

```
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(df$Text,language="english", minWordLength=1, #!
                          removePunctuation=TRUE, stripWhitespace=TRUE,
                          toLower=TRUE, removeStopwords=TRUE,
                          stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)
```

Now we get:

```
> dtMatrix$dimnames$Terms
```

[1] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "m" "r"

And more importantly:

```
> results 
  SVM_LABEL  SVM_PROB
1         1 0.9144185
```

I was on a workshop about RTextTools and SVM recently and they remarked that with SVM you get slightly different results every time you train a model. I'm not entirely sure why so I won't try to explain but we were recommended a free book called "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R" to read up on Support Vector Machines.

Here is the full code:

```
df <- structure(list(Text = structure(c(26L, 28L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 31L, 
                                        32L, 33L, 35L, 21L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 10L, 20L, 14L, 
                                        13L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 
                                        19L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("MRR   87149", "MRR 871984", "MRR 87345", 
                                                                 "MRR 873493", "MRR 873790", "MRR 873949", "MRR 874303", "MRR 874304", 
                                                                 "MRR 874343", "MRR 87678", "MRR 87678367", "MRR 877886", "MRR 878770", 
                                                                 "MRR 87890", "MRR 8790", "MRR 879034", "MRR 87943", "MRR 879430", 
                                                                 "MRR 879434", "MRR 87956", "MRR 92325", "MRR 93023", "MRR 930982", 
                                                                 "MRR 931932", "MRR 93204", "MRR 93345", "MRR 933922", "MRR 93434", 
                                                                 "MRR 934390", "MRR 93554", "MRR 937899", "MRR 93868", "MRR 938769", 
                                                                 "MRR 938900", "MRR 93930", "MRR 93970"), class = "factor"), Y = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                   -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                   -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L)), .Names = c("Text", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -36L))



df$Text <- as.character(df$Text)  
# new data
df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c("MRR    93111","")
df$Text <- sapply(1:length(df$Text), function(i) paste(unlist(strsplit(df$Text[i], split = "")), collapse = " "))

# Create the document term matrix
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(df$Text,language="english", minWordLength=1, 
                          removePunctuation=TRUE, stripWhitespace=TRUE,
                          toLower=TRUE, removeStopwords=TRUE,
                          stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998) 


dtMatrix$dimnames$Terms
dtMatrix$dimnames$Docs

# Configure the training data
container <- create_container(dtMatrix, df$Y, trainSize=1:36, testSize = 37, virgin=TRUE) 

container <- create_container(dtMatrix,
                              labels=df$Y, trainSize=1:36, testSize = 37, virgin=TRUE)

# train a SVM Model
model <- train_model(container, "SVM",kernel="linear" ,cost=1) ##??

results <- classify_model(container,model)

results
```

Comment: Thank you very much JonGrub, you have nailed the issue.

By the way i've not got why the "stripWhitespace" flag doesn't actually work. As per my understanding it should remove whitespaces so the training-set would be blank-free e.g: "MRR 93345" should be turned into "MRR93345" and treated as a unique lexeme.
In this case, we would have a less scattered matrix and the odds for matching the prediction which cointains "MRR93" are absolutely higher . 

But maybe I've missed something...

Comment: You got the wrong idea of what stripWhitespace does. From tm help: "The text document with multiple whitespace characters collapsed to a single blank". This can be useful since the way text is split to words is by extracting from one blank to the next. However, in RTexTools it does not seem to work at all as stripWhitespace=TRUE or FALSE has the same results. try with `dtMatrix <- create_matrix("MRR  bla  93111", stripWhitespace=TRUE)` and `dtMatrix$dimnames$Docs`

Comment: Ok, my idea was like it worked as a trim() function whereas it only basically reduces N whitespaces to 1. E.g: [MRR/x20/x20/x2093111]->[MRR 93111]

Comment: i'm getting this error after your function: `Error in strsplit(dt$Text[i], split = "") : non-character argument.`If i convert it into `strsplit(as.character(dt$Text[i]), split = ""` when the matrix is generated i get: `Error in [.simple_triplet_matrix(matrix, , sort(colnames(matrix))) : 
  Invalid subscript type: NULL.`

Comment: In the dput you provided your text was class factor (`class(df$Text)`). Try `df$Text <- as.character(df$Text) ` one line before. Factor objects are sometimes behaving weird... Update: nevermind that isn't the problem.

Comment: Are you using the excat same code above? There is an error where you create the matrix. it should be `data$Y` (with capital Y). I think I corrected it while trying it out.

Comment: Unfortunately I obtained the same error even moving it before

Comment: Yes, same code. Data$Y is declared after the line where i get the error

Comment: Sorry I saw that I forgot an important detail above :/ set option ´minWordLength=1´. Standard is minWordLength=3 which kicks out the single characters. I'll add it

Comment: Ok, fixed that error but now it's stuck on another one, precisely on the predictionContainer's line: Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “matrix.csr” object: ra has too few, or too many elements –

Comment: Not quite sure if I changed anything else important so I just pasted the whole code from top to bottom. I made a few smaller changes which I thought were not important since the code ran fine before (but gave wrong results)...

Comment: ok I let it work by also splitting predictionData, but the result is not such impressive... 1 M R R 9 3 7 8 7 -1 0.688376

Comment: Can you try ´rm(list=ls())´ and run everything again? The command empties your environment so no old models/data/objects interfere. That's all I can think of. I constantly get SVM_LABEL: 1  SVM_PROB: 0.9156523 (+/- 0.3)

Comment: No way... Do you get 1 for the following string? "M R R 9 3 7 8 7"? Because in your result (above) I read: 1 SVM_Label:1 SVM_Prob:0,91 Are you sure your prediction is not the string "1"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137932/discussion-between-unclejohn00-and-jongrub).